# Should MarkLogic on development server and MarkLogic on production be a part of one cluster?

Tags: admin, marklogic, marklogic-9

If you have MarkLogic installed on two hosts one is being used as a development server and another one is used as a production server, then should they not be a part of one group or one cluster. I mean if I go to the Admin interface of any one of them and I click on the clusters, should I not be able to see the names of both the hosts?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. Normally there are good reasons to want to keep dev, test, acceptance, and production environments isolated from each other. Data-access is one of them. And some environments could be in different network segments, because dev, test, acc often are internal only, and production sometimes needs to be in the DMZ.

You could potentially link them as foreign clusters, but since it is unlikely that you will do data replication between them, I don't think there is much point in doing so, other than admin user convenience, e.g. being able to see both environments from one admin screen.

HTH!

Comment: Also: it is not uncommon to load a copy of production data into the acceptance environment, but that doesn't require a link either. You can easily repurpose a production backup for that.